# Recent instructions for mdadm RAID-1 and LUKS setup on UEFI systems

Tags: uefi, encryption, raid, mdadm, luks

I have been trying to find a recent document on installing Ubuntu (18.04 preferred) using mdadm RAID-1 mirrors and LUKS underneath mdadm. The main point of using LUKS under the mdadm layer is that encryption only happens once, whereas encrypting volumes twice carries further overhead and is a waste of resources.

Unfortunately I haven't quite found anything for UEFI systems.

This question does have a great answer for those who are not deploying LUKS:
[Install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios)

While I suppose that it should be as simple as creating a LUKS container immediately under the mdadm volume, and then LVM on the 'opened' container, I do not want to make assumptions about how easy or automated the process is with the initramfs. In the past there were issues when crypt_root was sitting inside a RAID array.

Hopefully others can share what they know through here.

Comment: This was actually significantly harder than I expected, but I have documented my working setup here: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/installing-ubuntu-bionic-on-encrypted-raid1/