# Ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64 installation fails on Lenovo p52: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup CPU#0 stuck for 22s1 (Worker/0:2:86]

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lenovo, raid

I downloaded the Ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64 version and trying to install via USB key image on the following Lenovo P52 notebook.
The notebook has been preformatted so no Windows on it.

Notebook ThinkPad P52
Processor: Intel Core i9-8950HK MB
32GB(16+16) DDR4 2400MHz SODIMM
NVIDIA Quadro P3200 6GB
HDD Config: 2x1TB Solid State Drive, PCIe, TLC
RAID Setting: RAID0
Pointing device: 3+3BCP, Fingerprint Reader
WiFi wireless LAN adapters: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 2x2 AC, Bluetooth Version 5.0 vPro
TPM Setting: Hardware dTPM2.0 Enabled

After beginning the installation I got the following log (left truncated, OCR generated below):

[image: screenshot of error]

```
...)4 1-Libuntu
... oc/sys/kernel hun_ldsk_timeout_-_,ecs" disables this message.
...ker/9 :1: ] i h tuLI ed for more than 120 seconds.
...    4.18.0-15-generic #16A18.04.1-Ubuntu
...s/J erne hung_t ask _A imeout_secs" disables this message.
.../9: 2 : 270 blocked f or more than 120 seconds.
...d: G               L    4.18.0-15-generic WI6#18.04.1-Ubuntu
...iproc     /kerne 1/hung_t askt imeout_secs" disables this message.
...task WC.1 er/5:     35 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...4iiinted G                L    4.18.0-15-generic 1#16"18.04.1-Ubuntu
...IF> /proc /sys/l<erne 1/hung, t ask 2. imeout_secs" disables this
...message.
...task wpa_supp I icant : 1432 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...Tainted: G               L       18.0-15-generic #16"16.04.1-Ubuntu
...0 / /proc/sys/k erne 1 /huq_t ask_t imeout_secs" disables this message.
...tasi/ Xorg. mr ap 2191 blocked f or more than 120 seconds.
...Tainted: G               L    4.18.0-15-generic #16"11.04.1-Libuntu
...0 > /procisys/Verneistmeg_taskiimeautsecs" disables this message.
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPU#10 stuck for 22s1 Isystemda]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CHAO stuck for 22s1 [[ worker/0:2:86]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPU#10 stuck for 23s1 (systemd:1)
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPU#0 stuck for 22s1 [kworker/0:2:86)
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CP010 stuck for 23s1 Esystemd:11
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPU#0 stuck for 22sI [Worker/0:2:86]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPUW3 stuck for 22s1 (snapd:2578]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup     CPU#10 stuck for 23s1 isystemd:11
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup    CPU#0 stuck for 22s1 (Worker/0:2:86]
........
(and repeat and repeat...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem: the issue lies in

- ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64 desktop installer not supporting RAID (Both 0 and 1)
- the nouveau open-source graphics device driver for Nvidia Quadro video card provided with the installer is not working

Here the solution:

- Set Controller mode to AHCI ie no hardware raid: Bios -> Config -> Storage -> AHCI mode (solve the RAID problem, if you still want to install with software RAID0 or 1 see below)
- Insert the Ubuntu installation USB key
- Enter GRUB
- Go to install Ubuntu
- Press e to edit commands before booting
- Replace “quiet splash” with “nouveau.modeset=0” in the linux line
  (solve the Nvidia driver problem)
- Reboot

Now I see the Ubuntu installer welcome screen. 
After the first install  remove the usb key, reboot the system and press esc at boot time to enter GRUB.
In the grub menu select ubuntu, press e to edit and repeat the nouveau stuff ie replace “quiet splash” with “nouveau.modeset=0” in the linux line

Now you can enter ubuntu desktop and install the official ubuntu nvidia drivers:

Software & updates -> Additional drivers -> Choose nvidia proprietary tested -> apply -> restart

All done

---

### Software RAID0 or 1 installation notes:

Neither ubuntu desktop nor ubuntu server installer recognizes hardware controller RAID0 or 1.
To install Ubuntu with software RAID:

Disable the RAID hardware controllerin the  bios:
Bios -> Config -> Storage -> AHCI mode
Download the and install ubuntu server distribution ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso and follow this guide:
[Install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios)
Since the installer is text mode you won't have issues with nouveau driver.
Then you can install Gnome by command line