# Can I have RAID 1 with LVM and 4 drives on 18.04 LTS Server?

Tags: 18.04, raid, lvm

Can I create two LVMs with 2 drives each, totaling 4 drives, then set up RAID 1? The goal is to create two each 8 TB LVMs, then mirror them.

I've read the following post and several others all over and can't find anyone doing this with more than 2 physical drives, so maybe it can't be done & I'm nuts for trying it.

[Install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios)

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a live machine with four total drives: two each 2 TB SSD Hybrids, plus two each 6 TB HHDs.

I want to create an LVM using one 2 TB drive and one 6 TB drive and then repeat with the other two drives.

[image]

I have an SSD/Disk Hybrid for boot, the OS & the file system, save for one folder which will be mounted on the 6 TB HDD as dynamic storage. The 6 TB will have nothing else on it.

Then I want to implement RAID 1 to have a failover option.

If so, how? 
If not, how can I achieve the goal?

As an aside, I'll be backing up to an 8 TB external drive.

Comment: Have you considered using RAID 10?

Comment: As I understand RAID 10, and maybe I don't, don't all 4 disks have to be the same size?

Comment: No, they do not need to be identical but you might not be able to utilize all the space of the larger drives in the same raid array. I apologize, I guess I missed your point of that you want to utilize all the available space. I would go with `lvmraid` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just use [LVM RAID](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/lvmraid.7.html)

Basically, you do the following:

1. Create physical volumes of physical disk partitions. Do this the usual way using fdisk or if you prefer the graphical waya you can use Gnome disks or gparted. Then use `pvcreate` on the partitions.
2. Create volume groups of the physical volums. Use the command below in the terminal:

`sudo vgcreate VG_NAME /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb2`

use your VG_NAME --> this could be anything you like

use your partitions names in place of `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`

3. Create mirrored logical volumes.

> raid1
>
> ```
>    Also  called  mirroring,  raid1  uses  multiple devices to duplicate LV data.  The LV data
>    remains available if all but one of the devices fail.  The minimum number of devices (i.e.
>    sub LV pairs) required is 2.
>
>    lvcreate --type raid1 [--mirrors Number] VG [PVs]
>
>    --mirrors specifies the number of mirror images in addition to the original LV image, e.g.
>           --mirrors 1 means there are two images of the data, the  original  and  one  mirror
>           image.
>
>    PVs  specifies  the devices to use.  If not specified, lvm will choose Number devices, one
>    for each image.
> ```