# Understanding disk space partitioning

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a dedicated server with Ubuntu Server 18.04 (256 RAM, 2x 240 GB SSD) and here's how the disk space allocation looks now:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs            26G  1.7M   26G   1% /run
/dev/md2        219G  145G   64G  70% /
tmpfs           126G   12K  126G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop1      8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/88
/dev/md1        487M  146M  312M  32% /boot
tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 89.1 MiB, 93454336 bytes, 182528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 8.5 MiB, 8941568 bytes, 17464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe5bc9ccf

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         4096   1050623   1046528   511M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         1050624 467808255 466757632 222.6G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       467808256 468854783   1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd0864b40

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         4096   1050623   1046528   511M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         1050624 467808255 466757632 222.6G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       467808256 468854783   1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/md1: 511 MiB, 535756800 bytes, 1046400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 222.6 GiB, 238979842048 bytes, 466757504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I got a little bit confused by the fact that device names shown by `df -h` don't match the ones in `fdisk -l`.
Currently, I have access only to 1 SSD (/dev/md2) and I don't understand what the second SSD is used for and if (and how) it's possible to use disk space on it.

Comment: That looks like RAID. So whether RAID 0 or RAID 1 cannot tell. Best not to use RAID 0. Another RAID question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios & https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a RAID1 system with two mirrored hard drives (sda and sdb). Where `fdisk -l` shows you the real physical disks and their partitions, `df -h` shows you the raid devices and partitions as they are used by the system.

I.e. `/dev/md1` is made up from `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` which both have the same contents. If either drive fails the data is secure on the other one.

To get more details about the raid device, use `mdadm` (assuming is was done by that):

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md1
```

Comment: Or the command `cat /proc/mdstat` will show more detail to the Metadisk RAID drives.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man df`:

```
If  no file name is given, the space available on all
currently mounted file systems is shown.
```

And in `man fdisk`:

```
-l, --list
    List the partition tables for the specified devices and then exit. If  no  devices are given, 
those mentioned in /proc/partitions (if that file exists) are used.
```

So the difference is tha `df` shows *mounted* systems while `fdisk -l` (with no arguments) shows the partitions listed in `/proc/partitions`