# Booting previous OS partition is failing after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently switched from CentOS to Ubuntu. Grub can find my old CentOS /root XFS partition but fails to load it. At the emergency mode prompt I can manually mount the old centOS partition.

The journalctl log seem to imply that Grub thinks the partition is ext3 but it is XFS.

**journalctl says**

```
systemd[1]: Found device /dev/dm-5.
systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/dm-5...
systemd-fsck[2496]: fsck.ext3 doesn't exist, not checking file system on /dev/dm-5
systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/dm-5.
systemd[1]: Started dracut initqueue hook.
systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
systemd[1]: Mounting /sysroot...
mount[2522]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext3'
systemd[1]: sysroot.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
systemd[1]: Failed to mount /sysroot.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Initrd Root File System.
```

Comment: Did you format your disk before replacing the OS?  Did you intend to set up dual boot?  Ubuntu uses the ext4 file system by default.  Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/945337/ubuntu-17-04-will-not-boot-on-uefi-system-with-xfs-system-partition

Comment: Ubuntu is running properly but I can't boot into the old OS.  FWIW I installed Ubuntu into an existing LVM-ext3 partition that is working fine.  I can also mount the olde CentSO /root file system after ubuntu is running. So the file systems themselves are fine.  The problem IMO is in the grub configuration.  I already ran update-grub - no change.